# Getting error while inserting bulk data using bulkCreate in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to insert a lot of data i database using Sequelize library 
but it is showing some strange as I am passing an array of objects into the bulkCreate query .

I have function something like this

```
db.organizations
          .findAll({
            attributes: ['name'],
            where: {
              id: req.ORG_ID
            }
          })
          .then(org => {
            let i; let smsData = [];
            for (i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
              let DefaultText = Utils.defaultMessage(
                user[i].name,
                user[i].dataValues.amount,
                org[0].name
              );
              smsData.push({
                organizationId:
                  user[i].dataValues.organizationEntries[0].organizationId,
                mobile: user[i].mobile,
                message: DefaultText,
                status: 0
              });
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(smsData));
            db.logSms.bulkCreate([{
              smsData
            }]).then(() => { // Notice: There are no arguments here, as of right now you'll have to...
              return db.logSms.findAll({ where: { status: 0 } });
            }).then(sms => {
              console.log(sms)
            })
```

and I have also done console.log(smsData) which is showing array of objects but I am not able to understand why I am facing this error.

INSERT INTO `log_sms` (`id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (NULL,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Field 'mobile' doesn't have a default value

This error is basically coming as while executing the query as u can see below the error as I have made mobile field compulsory and I am passing the array of objects which is having mobile number but still this error is coming. Please give some hint

Answer (score 0):

I have got my mistake as I should remove the braces from this statement:

```
db.logSms.bulkCreate([{ smsData }])
```

it should be like this:

```
db.logSms.bulkCreate(smsData)
```